# Save Multiple textareas with CKEditor 5

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, phalcon

I set CKEditor 5 to more than one , the editors all show up fine, but only the first one i can save on db.

I change the name of each textarea. The first one is line[0][descSoftware], the next is line[1][descSoftware], etc.

When i write var_dump($_POST); on form. The next array (descSoftware) doesn't bring me any string:

```
array(2) {
["nameSoftware"]=>
string(4) "Test"
["soft"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
["typeSoftware"]=>
string(4) "test"
["versionSoftware"]=>
string(1) "1"
["descSoftware"]=>
string(12) "
test1
"
}
[1]=>
array(3) {
["typeSoftware"]=>
string(5) "test2"
["versionSoftware"]=>
string(1) "2"
["descSoftware"]=>
string(0) ""
}
}
}
```

My view is php, i'm using Phalcon as a framework:

```
$formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('br');
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('div',['class' => 'col-xs-12']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('h4', ['class' => 'box-title']);
            $formSoftwares .= 'Versão Nº: ';
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('span', ['class' => 'line']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('span');
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('h4');
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('div');
            //Campo tipo do software
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('div',['class' => 'col-xs-4']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('label', ['for' => 'typeSoftware']);
            $formSoftwares .= 'Tipo de software:';
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('label');
            $formSoftwares .= $form->render('typeSoftware',['name' => 'soft[0][typeSoftware]', 'require' => '']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('div');
            //Campo Versão do software
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('div',['class' => 'col-xs-4']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('label', ['for' => 'versionSoftware']);
            $formSoftwares .= 'Versão do Software:';
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('label');
            $formSoftwares .= $form->render('versionSoftware',['name' => 'soft[0][versionSoftware]', 'require' => '']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('div');
            //botões add e remove
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('div',['class' => 'col-xs-4']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('button',['style' => 'margin-top: 21px;font-size: 15px', 'type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary addSoftware', 'id' => 'addSoftware']);
            //$formSoftwares .= '+';
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('i', ['class' => 'fa fa-plus']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('i');
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('button');
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('div');
            // Campo descrição
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('div',['class' => 'col-xs-12', 'style' => 'margin-top: 15px']);
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtml('label', ['for' => 'descSoftware']);
            $formSoftwares .= 'Descrição: ';
            $formSoftwares .= $this->tag->tagHtmlClose('label');
            $formSoftwares .= $form->render('descSoftware',['name' => 'soft[0][descSoftware]', 'require' => '']);
            $formSoftwares .= $form->render('fileSoftware');
            $this->view->formSoftwares = $formSoftwares;
```

Jquery, use to add a new row:

```
function addRow() {
    $(document).on('click', '#addSoftware', function(){

        var line = 0;
        $('.line').each(function(i,v){
            line = i + 1;
        });
        var html = $(this).parent().parent().html();

        html = html.replace('primary', 'warning');
        html = html.replace('plus', 'minus');
        html = html.replace('addSoftware', 'removeSoftware');
        html = html.replace(/soft\[0\]/g, 'soft['+line+']');

        $('#addWrapper').append('<div = class="block">'+html+'</div>');
        countRow();
        //maskPayment();
        removeRow();
    });
}
```

Jquery, Ckeditor 5:

```
    function getCkeditor() {
        let editorDescricao = null;

        ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector(".descSoftware"), {
            language: 'pt-br',
          })
            .then(editor => {
              editorDescricao = editor;
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
```

How can i proceed?

Thanks for help!

Comment: share you html please.

Comment: Sorry, i add my code now.

Comment: Share the page source after the form is rendered please.